# Defining test parameters in their own file

Tags: testing, system-testing

In many of my system tests I test a particular functionality for all modes. For example, in this test I test the alarm functionality for all modes:

```
modes = ("start","stop","restart","stage1","stage2")
max_alarm_time = 10

# test alarm for all modes
def test_alarm():
    for m in modes:
       target.set_mode(m)
       assert target.alarm() < max_alarm_time
```

Is it valid in your opinion if I remove the definition of modes from each test and move it into its own file? Therefore should my modes change I won't need to update every test.

```
import test_parameters
max_alarm_time = 10

# test alarm for all modes
def test_alarm():
    for m in test_parameters.modes:
       target.set_mode(m)
       assert target.alarm() < max_alarm_time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it valid in your opinion if I remove the definition of modes from each test and move it into its own file?

Yes it is: saving [fixtures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture#Software) in files is common practice.

Beside that, as you have noticed, your test became more maintainable.